# Pandas Dataframe Merge on 2 Columns Including Conditional If Merge: If Date in df_2 is Between Two Other Dates in df_1

Tags: python, pandas, date, merge, between

I have the following sample data frames:

df_1:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame( 
 {"SVDiscrep_Merge": ["2081916SAN", "2081242DFW", "2081248ORD","20874CLE", "2081740DEN"],
 "RON_DATE": [datetime(2017,6,1), datetime(2017,6,4), datetime(2017,6,6), datetime(2017,6,7), datetime(2017,6,8)],
 "Next SV1 Date": [datetime(2017,6,4), datetime(2017,6,6), datetime(2017,6,7), datetime(2017,6,8), datetime(2017, 6, 18)]})

>>> df_1

SVDiscrep_Merge     RON_DATE    Next SV1 Date
2081916SAN          6/1/2017    6/4/2017    
2081242DFW          6/4/2017    6/6/2017
2081248ORD          6/6/2017    6/7/2017
20874CLE            6/7/2017    6/8/2017
2081740DEN          6/8/2017    6/18/2017
```

df_2:

```
>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame( 
 {"SVDiscrep_Merge": ["2081916SAN", "2081916SAN", "2081916SAN","2081740DEN"],
 "REPORT_DT": [datetime(2017,6,1), datetime(2017,6,3), datetime(2017,6,4), datetime(2017,6,9)],
 "ColA": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]})

>>> df_2

SVDiscrep_Merge REPORT_DT   ColA
2081916SAN      6/1/2017    A
2081916SAN      6/3/2017    B
2081916SAN      6/4/2017    C
2081740DEN      6/9/2017    D
```

I want to employ the following logic:

1. Left merge `df_2` into `df_1` if (and only if) `SVDiscrep_Merge` is equal in both dataframes and
2. `REPORT_DT` column is >= date in `RON_DATE` and < date in `Next SV1 Date` in `df_1`.

This is my desired output:

```
SVDiscrep_Merge     RON_DATE    Next SV1 Date  ColA 
2081916SAN          6/1/2017    6/4/2017       A    
2081916SAN          6/4/2017    6/6/2017       B
2081916SAN          6/6/2017    6/7/2017
2081242DFW          6/4/2017    6/6/2017    
2081248ORD          6/6/2017    6/7/2017
20874CLE            6/7/2017    6/8/2017
2081740DEN          6/8/2017    6/18/2017      D
```

I know how to do the merge in python code if I did not have that date logic... but with that date logic (after searching Google) I am at a loss.

Comment: How did `B` end up in a row with `2081242DFW`?

Comment: Is your dataset prohibitively large, or are we talking about something where you don't need to be super worried about space?

Comment: Are you sure your `df_2` is correct?

Comment: apologies.... you guys are right I made an error

Answer (score 2):

You could left merge on `SVDiscrep_Merge`, then filter the result using the following boolean mask:

```
mask = (((result['RON_DATE'] <= result['REPORT_DT']) 
         & (result['REPORT_DT'] < result['Next SV1 Date'])) 
        | pd.isnull(result['REPORT_DT']))
```

---

```
import datetime as DT 
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame( 
 {"SVDiscrep_Merge": ["2081916SAN", "2081242DFW", "2081248ORD","20874CLE", "2081740DEN"],
 "RON_DATE": [DT.datetime(2017,6,1), DT.datetime(2017,6,4), DT.datetime(2017,6,6), DT.datetime(2017,6,7), DT.datetime(2017,6,8)],
 "Next SV1 Date": [DT.datetime(2017,6,4), DT.datetime(2017,6,6), DT.datetime(2017,6,7), DT.datetime(2017,6,8), DT.datetime(2017, 6, 18)]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame( 
 {"SVDiscrep_Merge": ["2081916SAN", "2081916SAN", "2081916SAN","2081740DEN"],
 "REPORT_DT": [DT.datetime(2017,6,1), DT.datetime(2017,6,3), DT.datetime(2017,6,4), DT.datetime(2017,6,9)],
 "ColA": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]})

result = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='SVDiscrep_Merge',  how='left')
mask = (((result['RON_DATE'] <= result['REPORT_DT']) 
         & (result['REPORT_DT'] < result['Next SV1 Date'])) 
        | pd.isnull(result['REPORT_DT']))
result = result.loc[mask].drop('REPORT_DT', axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
  Next SV1 Date   RON_DATE SVDiscrep_Merge ColA
0    2017-06-04 2017-06-01      2081916SAN    A
1    2017-06-04 2017-06-01      2081916SAN    B
3    2017-06-06 2017-06-04      2081242DFW  NaN
4    2017-06-07 2017-06-06      2081248ORD  NaN
5    2017-06-08 2017-06-07        20874CLE  NaN
6    2017-06-18 2017-06-08      2081740DEN    D
```

This is not quite the desired result you posted, but it is consistent with the description of the logic.

Comment: you are absolutely right!  thank you so much; I did make a mistake in my  desired output table